# changing postgres port for airflow with docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, airflow

I am currently using the official `docker-compose` file provided from the Airflow website, with some minor adjustments and build off a `Dockerfile`:

```
version: "3"
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: ./airflow
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__PARALLELISM: 32
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAG_CONCURRENCY: 16
    AIRFLOW__CORE__MAX_ACTIVE_RUNS_PER_DAG: 16
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ""
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "false"
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth"
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"',
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest-python3.8

RUN pip uninstall  --yes azure-storage && pip install -U azure-storage-blob apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure==1.1.0

RUN pip install pandas==1.3.0
RUN pip install SQLAlchemy==1.4.22
RUN pip install numpy==1.21.0
RUN pip install boto3==1.18.6
```

I am trying to run some tests and connect to my local postgresql database (I don't want to use the postgresql database that airflow is using in the image), but I realized that the ports are the same for the `docker-compose` file and my localhost port.  I am receiving this error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Should I change the ports in the postgres image?

Comment: No need to change the port.  Seems like postgres is not running where Airflow thinks it's running -- you may want to confirm that `listen_addresses` is set to `*` and not `localhost`.  You may also want to add `hostname: postgres` to your `postgres:` service in the `docker-compose.yml` file

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    command: -p 5433
```

See also
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/connections/postgres.html